# How to write a regular expression that removes the first number and everything after in a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

How to write a regular expression that removes the first number and everything after in a string in Javascript?

Example:

John.Doe12@somewhere.net

to

John.Doe

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.replace()` like this:

```
var result = str.replace(/\d+.*$/, "");
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/97kMW/

Comment: Thanks... do you know any good resources on learning to write regex?

Comment: @user1693131 - there are hundreds of great web pages on regex.  I'd suggest you start with a Google search for "javascript regular expression" and pick out the pages that best show you what you want to know.

Comment: @user1693131 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp